# Java Regex: Match text between two strings with boundary conditions

Tags: java, regex, parsing, match

I want to match text between two Strings, but the starting String has strict boundary conditions.

Sample input:

```
start
From: h
From:b
 xyz
Subject: 
end
```

I need to match between `From:` and `Subject:`.

If I use `(From:.*).*(Subject:)` with dotall, it produces

```
From: h
From:b
 xyz
Subject:
```

but I need only

```
From:b
 xyz
Subject:
```

because the starting string has strict boundary conditions. This is necessary because the starting String could be anywhere in the document, and then the above regex will match a big text rather than just few lines.

%%%%%%%%%%%% Problem redefined %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
I have text in which I need to match:

```
From:<any text>
To:<any text>
Subject:<any text>
```

The catch is that: All the three components can be in one line, could be separated by one newline, or could be separated by 2 newlines... There are text before and after the desired match which could contain `From:<any text>`, that's why I need strict boundaries.

Comment: You keep redefining your problem and the text that you want to match.  This will depreciate old answers that were posted when you originally created this question.  Please stick to your original question, or make the question as clear as possible when you create it.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience but I think I did not change the question or desired pattern. In my original question, I had `From:` two times, because it's the actual text.. In the edit, I had mentioned what exactly I need from that and also declared that anything could be present before and after the desired pattern.

Comment: Also, I added the comment `%%%% problem redefined %%%%`, because when two people posted the solution and both were incorrect, I thought I was not clear enough to describe the question. That's why I redefined the problem hoping to give a better understanding of the problem. I did not meant to confuse anyone. I am Sorry if I did that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
String input = "start From: h From:b xyz Subject: end";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=^((?!From:).)*(From: [A-Za-z0-9] ))(.+?)(Subject:)").matcher(input);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output: `From:b xyz Subject:`.

---

Explanation of regex (`(?<=^((?!From:).)*(From: [A-Za-z0-9] ))(.+?)(Subject:)`):

- `(?<=` start looking behind
- `^` the start of the string
- `((?!From:).)` if looking ahead and you can't see "From:" then match any character
- `*` matches the previous statement zero or more times
- `(From: [A-Za-z0-9] ))` matches the first "From:" and it's contents
- `)` stop looking behind
- `(.+?)` matches the string we are looking for
- `(Subject:)` matches the subject field

Comment: How did you test this?  Java doesn't support unbounded lookbehinds (but some versions have a bug that causes them to forget that and try anyway).  Also, the OP's data is in the form of multiple lines, not all on one line like you have it.  (The OP may have edited the question while you were writing your answer.  If you do that quickly enough, SO doesn't flag the question as edited.)

Comment: It's not giving correct result. I tried with input `"start From: h strt From:b xyz Subject: end"` and it matches `strt From:b xyz Subject:`, which is incorrect. I need everything starting from `From:`

Comment: @AlanMoore It doesn't?  I tested it in Eclipse with Java 7, and it worked fine...

Comment: ohhh. I dont know why. I am using Netbeans with Java 7 and it gave me different answer.. Input: `"start From: h strt From:b xyz Subject: end"`.. output: `strt From:b xyz Subject:` with the regex `(?<=^((?!From:).)*(From: [A-Za-z0-9] ))(.+?)(Subject:)`

Comment: @user2200660 Your input is different in this comment then supplied originally in your question.  Therefore, your output is expected to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.*` in DOTALL mode, I suggest you match one line at a time, *after* asserting that the line doesn't start with `From:`.

```
"(?m)^From:.*[\r\n]+(?:(?!From:).*[\r\n]+)*Subject:.*$"
```

That's the minimum implementation.  Depending on how your text is structured, it could still match too much or too slowly (especially in cases where no match is possible).  Here's a more robust version:

```
"(?m)^(?>From:.*[\r\n]+)(?>(?!From:|Subject:).*[\r\n]+)*+Subject:.*$"
```

Comment: It's not working for the example shown... I will explain the problem once again in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the multiline modifier and negative lookahead:

[`(?s)From:((?!From:).)*?Subject:`](https://regex101.com/r/rH7mU6/2) [<kbd>@ regex101</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/rH7mU6/2)

NOTE: the regex101 fiddle contains the live regex and test data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
From\:\w*(?!From\:\w*)\n*\w*\n*Subject:\w*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mX9kC7/3